# The set that only contains itself

Tags: set-theory, recursion

Ignoring the axiom of regularity (and therefore the implication of "no set can contain itself"), would it be correct to state that the set that contains only itself is unique?

My argument is that if $x$ is said set, then
$$ x = \{x\} = \{\{x\}\} = \{\{\{\cdot\cdot\cdot\}\}\} $$
Ad infinitum, which seems to be unique.

Comment: If there is such a set, that is. Can you prove its existence?

Comment: You could say that $\{\ldots\{1\}\ldots\} \neq\{\ldots\{2\}\ldots\}$ yet both seem to satisfy your definition.

Comment: @DarthGeek I would think any set that is at least $\omega$ "deep" before something that is not just curly braces would satisfy this.

Comment: That's not an argument. A set $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$ is sometimes called a "Quine atom". There can be any number of Quine atoms. If I remember right, Quine proposed identifying such things with physical objects.

Comment: Couldn't we distinguish these things by the cardinality of the number of braces?  Then Arthur's "$\omega$ deep" could be broadened to "limit cardinal deep".

Comment: @DarthGeek What are those sets exactly? How do you construct them? Or at least write them down without ellipses. The set the asker is talking about could be characterized as a fixed point of the function $x ↦ \{x\}$.

Comment: I guess you could construct it as the "projective limit" of $\{S\} \leftarrow \{\{S\}\} \leftarrow \{\{\{S\}\}\} \ldots$. Where $S$ is any set. Formally, for different $S$ you have a different projective limit.

Comment: @GregRos: in ordinary ZF(C), Quine atoms of course can’t exist.  In ZF(C) minus regularity/foundation, it is consistent (as per bof’s comment) that there is a unique Quine atom, or many, or none.  Aczel’s anti-foundation axiom implies existence of a unique Quine atom.  Barwise and Moss “Vicious Circles” (referenced in amd’s answer) covers this.

Comment: I don't really understand much on the matter, to be honest, but assuming that $\{\{...\{1\}...\}\}$ can be one of those sets, seems incorrect to me. Given that any "subset" would contain itself, wouldn't it be saying that that last 1 is the whole thing as well?

Comment: Imagine that $x$ and $y$ are both Quine atoms (i.e. $x=\{x\}$ and $y=\{y\}$). Well, by definition, two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements. That is, the statement $x=y$, which we can write as $\{x\}=\{y\}$ because they're Quine atoms, is true if and only if… $x=y$. That wasn't particularly useful. (This doesn't show that it's possible to have two Quine atoms, just that this particular line of reasoning doesn't work.)

Answer (score 14):

It need not be unique; in fact, you can weaken the axiom of foundation to allow either well-founded sets or sets of the form $x=\{x\}$. Sets of the latter form are called *Quine atoms*, and play the role of [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement). These are useful in [set theory with atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_model) because they allow you to formulate a theory of sets-and-atoms without resorting to multi-sorted logic.

For more, see [*The Axiom of Choice*](http://orianhealth.com/media/Axiom_of_Choice.pdf) by T. J. Jech.

Answer (score 9):

In *Vicious Circles*, Barwise and Moss explore circularities like these that can result when the ZF Axiom of Foundation is dropped. In their presentation, uniqueness of solution of the equation $x=\{x\}$ and others like it must be added as an axiom.